# How to show parking near a specific area using Google API?

Tags: api, search, google-places-api, google-search-api, parking

I'm trying to show parking around a specific location using the place_id. I'm pretty sure it's just a simple issue, but I'm unable to find the solution in the documentation.

I've tried using origin=place_id: I've tried all variations of place_id; placeid; place_id:.

I'm using this as an example, it's from Google (URL for reference = https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start):

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=parking&key={apikey}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is my URL currently:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=parking&origin=place_id:ChIJkUJ52ya_QIYR4RcaJ2Z_RYE&radius=100&key={apikey}
```

If there's a way to use lat long, that's fine as well. Really just need to be able to show parking around specific locations.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The proper implementation would be supply the "parking near" plus the address in the q parameter, since you have a Place ID, you may geocode this to get the well-formatted address to be supplied in the q parameter, the final URL would be:

```html
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=parking%20near%20501%20Crawford%20St%2C%20Houston%2C%20TX%2077002%2C%20USA&key=AIzaSyAj0aaMu_aY6xiDSWH0ac_4pqN_l-opwmI" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```